# How to tell if a user is a fan of the fan page

Tags: facebook, fbml

I'm working on a FBML fan page for a client.  I need to perform a check to see if the current user is a fan of the page.  I tried using the JavaScript API but I've found this is not compatible with FBML.

I have looked through the FBML page on the developer wiki and found checks for practically everything else but no **is user fan** check.

Any pointers in the right direction would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this instead:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/visible-to-connection/

Please don't make those "Become a fan 1st" pages with it though. They're basically spam.

Comment: they're actually allowed in the terms and conditions : see 4.2 http://www.facebook.com/promotions_guidelines.php

Comment: Facebook's guidelines aren't always in a user's best interests.

Comment: example of such a page : facebook.com/deltaco - then click on the Free Taco tab (active as of today)

Answer (score 2):

Try this page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/pages.isFan/

Comment: Cheers but this is a call to the FB JavaScript API which you can't do in static FBML pages.  This was my first approach.

Comment: This is not the javascript API. This is a command for the REST API (http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/API). Your server will need to call this through the REST API.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good article - for doing this task in fan page tabs (most easily done with [the static FBML app](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=4949752878)).

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/how-to-detect-fan-of-a-facebook-page/

Be sure to read the fine print - such as if you’re admin of facebook page, you all time see the fan restricted item and non fan restricted item.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to parse signed_request. This method does not need app authorization by user.

```
$signed = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'], 'YOUR-APP-SECRET');
if ($signed['page']['liked'] == 1) {
    $fan = true;
} else {
    $fan = false;
}
```

[Here is a guide](http://jobyj.in/api/check-user-is-fan-of-facebook-page/) to Check User is Fan of Facebook.